# Finding the column with highest value within one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is how the table looks like

```
Jan | Feb | Mar | ~
10  | 20  | 10  | ~
```

I can find the highest value using `GREATEST` function.

```
SELECT GREATEST(Jan,Feb,Mar,~) FROM table
```

Now, I want to find the month with the highest value. I can try to compare the result of `GREATEST` function with individual column values. However, I feel that there should be a more elegant and easy to read solution.

Comment: Poor table design, have separate rows for each month instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I can not change the table as it is maintained and used by others. Any other idea?

Comment: In that case I find GREATEST(Jan,Feb,Mar,~) both elegant and easy to read!

Comment: The greatest function returns the greatest value. I want to find the month with the greatest value.

Comment: I see, you want the Month name too.

Comment: Yes. I want the column name with highest value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that works for me:

```
SELECT month FROM t1
WHERE num =
(
  SELECT MAX(num)FROM t1
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87ffd/12/0

Comment: This is returning the complete row. I am trying to look into columns within one row and then finding out which column has highest value.

Comment: So are you just looking to return the month with the hightest value ie Feb?

Comment: Yes. I just need to find out which month has the highest value (not the highest value itself).

Comment: The table structure in your fiddle is different from what I have. I have Jan, Feb, Mar, etc as columns.

Comment: Yes I see that.  I seem to be able to get the column name (Feb) and value 20 in result set, but not just Feb on its own :(

Comment: Thanks for the effort though. Giving brownie points! :) I ended up using a case statement for matching. It is quite verbose.